# Why the result showing same values against different numbers?

Tags: mysql, database, distinct

I am working on a query in which I am getting a list of `meter numbers` along with there `subdivision names`.

But when I run my query it's giving me same `subdivision` names against different meter numbers.

The query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT ms.`id` AS 'meter_id', ms.`meter_msn` AS 'Meter_Serial_Number', u.`name` AS 'Issued_To' 
,ps.`name` AS 'Store', sd.`name` AS 'Name',ms.`historic` AS 'Meter_Version' 
FROM `meters` ms
INNER JOIN `ogp_header` ogph ON ms.`issued_user` = ogph.`issuer` 
INNER JOIN `project_store` ps ON ogph.`store_id` = ps.`id` 
INNER JOIN `user` u ON `ogph`.`issuer` = u.`id`
INNER JOIN `issue_meters` im ON ps.`id` = im.`store_id`
INNER JOIN `survey_hesco_subdivision` sd ON im.`sub_division` = 
sd.`sub_div_code`
WHERE ms.`meter_status` = 'Installation Ready' AND ms.`id` NOT IN (SELECT 
DISTINCT ogpd.`meter_id` FROM `ogp_detail` ogpd WHERE ogpd.`flag` IN (1,2))
GROUP BY ms.`id`
ORDER BY ms.`id`
```

The result is

[image]

All these 6 meters are from different sub-divisions(NAME in the Result). How can I arrange the query in such a way that there will be distinct subdivision names?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: A group by with no aggregate functions and a distinct clause is unlikely to be correct,

Comment: @P.Salmon so what you suggest?

Comment: I guess from the code that you encountered duplicates and tried to get round this with group bys and distinct, without sample data I can only suggest that you remove all the joins and start adding them back to identify the one(s) which throw duplicates. If you could add sample data to your question as text or to sql fiddle then someone may be able to help you get to a resolution.